# Backwards evolution arising from changing evolution picture

Tags: quantum-optics, hamiltonian

This may not be a question strictly belonging to the realm of quantum computing, but it does arise from problems in QI and optics, so I choose to ask it here. Suppose $A$ is a Hermitian operator generating the unitary evolution $U=\exp(-i\theta A)$ for some real parameter $\theta$ (not necessarily time), and let $a^\dagger$ be a creation operator acting on the bosonic Fock space. In the Heisenberg picture, one may find the evolved operator $a'^\dagger(\theta):= U^\dagger a^\dagger U$ by solving Heisenberg's equation $$\dot a'^\dagger(\theta) = i[H, a'^\dagger(\theta)]. $$
Let us turn to the Schroedinger picture, and consider the one-particle state $|\psi\rangle=a^\dagger |\emptyset\rangle$ obtained by acting with the creation operator on the empty ket $|\emptyset\rangle$. Such a state evolves under the action of $U$ as
$$U|\psi\rangle = (Ua^\dagger U^\dagger)U|\emptyset\rangle = Ua^\dagger U^\dagger |\emptyset\rangle $$ where we have made use of the property of unitary invariance of the empty ket. We see that this corresponds to evolving $a^\dagger$ 'backwards' with respect to the parameter $\theta$, so $U|\psi\rangle=a'^\dagger(-\theta)|\emptyset\rangle$.

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this inversion, at least for some of operators that are useful in QI & quantum optics. For the sake of concreteness, consider the unitary $U=\exp i\theta(a^\dagger b+b^\dagger a)$ associated to a beam splitter interfering the independent modes $a, b$. Then up to a relative phase $a^\dagger$ evolves in the Heisenberg picture as
$$a'^\dagger(\theta) = \cos(\theta) a^\dagger + \sin(\theta) b^\dagger $$ and therefore according to the argument above the state $|\psi\rangle=a^\dagger|\emptyset\rangle$ going through the beam splitter undergoes the evolution
\begin{align*}
U|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta)a^\dagger |\emptyset\rangle - \sin(\theta) b^\dagger |\emptyset\rangle.
\end{align*}
What is the physical interpretion of this change of sign, and how does it generalize to the action of $U$ on any (coherent, multi-photon, etc) Fock state?